# How to format the id column with SHA1 digests in Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

Without saving SHA1 digest string in table directly. Is it possible to format the column in select statement ?

For example (Hope you know what i mean):

```
@item = Item.where(Digest::SHA1.hexdigest id.to_s:'356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not the way you want it. The `hexdigest` method you're using won't be available at the database level. You could use database-specific functions though.

For example:

```
Item.where("LOWER(name) = ?", entered_name.downcase)
```

The `LOWER()` function will be available to the database so it can pass the `name` column to it.

For your case, I can suggest two solutions:

1. Obviously, store the encrypted field in the table. And then match.

   ```
   key = '356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab'
   Item.where(encrypted_id: key)
   ```
2. Iterate over all column values (ID, in your case) and find the one that matches:

   ```
   all_item_ids = Item.pluck("CAST(id AS TEXT)")
   item_id = all_item_ids.find{ |val| Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(val) == key }
   ```

   Then you could use `Item.find(item_id)` to get the item or `Item.where(id: item_id)` to get an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, Humza. It works. If the type of id is integer, the find statement should be as follow: 

    `item_id = all_item_ids.find{ |val| Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(val.to_s) == key }`

Comment: Yup, I missed that. Alternatively you could cast the column as string. Might give better speed by not doing `to_s` later for each id. I've updated my response to reflect this.

Comment: For postgres, `create extension pg_crypto; CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sha1(bytea) returns text AS $$ SELECT encode(digest($1, 'sha1'), 'hex'); $$ LANGUAGE SQL STRICT IMMUTABLE;` and now `sha1(name)` will work, provided name is a string